# How could you make a polarity-switched electromagnet at home?

Tags: electromagnetism, switching

For context, I have lots of electrical parts and I am looking into ways to make a small polarity-switched electromagnet out of the parts I have. I can Information on the parts I have if needed. If necessary, I can buy more. Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome. A "polarity switched electromagnet"?  Do you mean an electromagnet which only becomes a magnet when some DC (a battery?) is connected one way rond and not the other?

Comment: @jonathanjo I’m sorry, I worded that badly. By polarity-switched I literally mean that the polarity of the magnet switches every x amount of time. There’s probably another term for it, but idk what it is.

Comment: What sort of time period is x?  Milliseconds?  Hours?  Makes a huge difference!  How long does it have to run for?  How strong does it need to be -- it matters if you're picking up iron filings, paperclips, cars.

Comment: @jonathanjo for the time period id say every 10ms or so, but that can be adjusted to fit the needs. Only picking up small objects like staples and paper clips, as you said.

Comment: 10 milliseconds "or so" is easy!  Use (say) 12V AC at 50 Hz, which you can get from a transformer.  Then you feed your electromagnet, just a coil.  At that speed, however, you'll find things like staples have too much inertia and the magnet behaves like a continuous magnet.

Comment: @jonathanjo Ah, I should have known. Sorry, it was a stupid question.

Comment: What do you mean by polarity in this context; voltage or current? What inductance are you considering? What DC resistance? What power supply?